# Outlook appoinment adding from xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, outlook, xamarin.mac

I want to add appointment dates with content in Mac Microsoft outlook calendar from my Xamarin.Mac application. Is it possible to do this .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a programmatic API but you should be be able to generate .ics files which are plain text and a well documented format, when clicked they can open in outlook, or any other decent calendar app, and saved

Comment: How to generate .ics file from Xamarin.mac app? is there any api is there to create .ics file ?

Comment: Some simple examples here, but it's just a text file with a .ics extension, the OS handles the rest https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

Answer (score 0):

[AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) would be the way to do this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set theSubject to "Test Appointment"
    set theContent to "HTML based content here"
    set myDate to current date

    set newAppointment to make new calendar event with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, start time:myDate + 1 * hours, end time:myDate + (2 * hours)}

    open newAppointment

end tell
```

You could create these scripts on the fly in C#, save them as a tmp file and execute them via `osascript` from the cmd line (via a Process.Start).

Open the [Apple Script Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor) and load the Dictionary for your version of Outlook, i.e: Outlook 2016/Calendar Suite's calendar event contains all of the following properties:

```
calendar event n [inh. categorizable object > object > item] : A calendar event.
properties
subject (text) : The subject of an event.
start time (date) : The time at which an event begins.
end time (date) : The time at which an event ends.
location (text) : The location of an event.
content (text) : The HTML description of the event.
plain text content (text) : The description of the event as plain text.
has html (boolean, r/o) : Indicates whether the description of the event has html text?
all day flag (boolean) : A flag for whether or not an event is an all day event.
has reminder (boolean) : Indicates whether or not an event has a reminder.
reminder time (integer) : The number of minutes from the start time of an event when a reminder will fire (if it has one).
free busy status (busy/‌free/‌tentative/‌out of office) : The free/busy status for an event.
exchange id (text, r/o) : The exchange identifier of an event (only applicable for events belonging to exchange accounts).
modification date (date, r/o) : The date an event was last modified on.
recurrence (recurrence or missing value) : The calendar recurrence.
is recurring (boolean, r/o) : Indicates whehter an event is part of a recurring series of events.
is occurrence (boolean, r/o) : Indicates whether an event is an occurrence of a recurring series.
recurrence id (date, r/o) : The recurrence id of an event (the date at which the recurring event occurs).
master (calendar event, r/o) : The master event for an event that is an exception from a recurring series.
is private (boolean) : Indicates whether an event is private.
calendar (calendar, r/o) : The calendar folder in which an event is filed.
account (account, r/o) : The account associated with an event.
organizer (text, r/o) : The organizer of the meeting.
timezone (timezone) : The timezone of an event.
request responses (boolean) : Indicates whether a response is requested from the attendees of the meeting.
icalendar data (text, r/o) : The information of an event in iCalendar format. Use the 'import ics' command to create an event from iCalendar information.
```